# ZF2 Dynamic Form Filters/Validators

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

I'm setting up a controller that will create a form.
I can't use an extended to Form class, so i need to build up my form on my controller.

```
$form = new Form('example');
$fieldset = new Fieldset('default');
$fieldset->add(array('name' => 'example_field', 'attributes' => array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'example_field'), 'options' => array('label' => 'Example Field',),));
$form->add($fieldset);
```

The main question here is, how do I define the filters and validators for each element/fieldset without required to create a class implementing InputFilterAwareInterface, so i can do everything from my controller?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain why you can not build a Form and attach it's validators? What dynamics do your form have that you are unable to build?

Answer (score 2):

You could add/remove form Validators by handle InputFilter of form, here is my example:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$name = array(
        'name' => 'username',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Your name',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text'
        ),
);
$form->add($name);


$filter = $form->getInputFilter();
$filter->remove('username');
$filter->add(array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array (
        'stringLength' => array (
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array (
                'max' => '3',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
$form->setInputFilter($filter);


$form->setData(array(
    'username' => 'longtext',
));
$form->prepare();
echo $form->isValid(); //false
print_r($form->getMessages()); //stringLengthTooLong error will show
```

Comment: It works althou when I setup a fieldset, with their validators and then create an collection with that same fieldset as target element, the validators dont find the right fields.. it seems like it stops at the array iterator from the collection..

Instead of searching for [form][collection][0][element].. it ignores the [0]..

Maybe im just getting it wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Add validator dynamically:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('element_name')->getValidatorChain()->attach(new ValidatorClassName());
```

Add filter dynamically:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('element_name')->getFilterChain()->attach(new FilterClassName());
```